# Understanding KVO in iOS

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

Regarding "Ensuring KVO Compliance",
there are some official definition which seem like hard to understand

> In order to be considered
>   KVO-compliant for a specific property,
>   a class must ensure the following;
>
> 1. The class must be key-value coding
>      compliant for the property as
>      specified in Ensuring KVC Compliance.
> 2. The class must allow automatic
>      observer notifications for the
>      property, or implement manual
>      key-value observing for the property.

Who can give more specific examples to make this more clear ?  Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [Ensuring KVO Compliance](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE) the Automatic Versus Manual Support section of the Key-Value Observing Programming Guide. Compliance is essentially achieved by following naming conventions for methods and/or ivars.

In my experience KVO tends to 'just work', which is nice.

Comment: Link rot: "Ensuring KVO Compliance" has moved to http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE

Answer (score 1):

When you use @property tags to [create getters/ setters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-BAJEAIEE) the magic is auto wired for To-One relationships and you only need to addObserver... and implement the observe... method to catch the updates.

The real challenge is understanding how you implement To-Many Key Value Compliance to make a mutable set or array work.  The [documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-178830-BAJEDEFB) is key and the understanding that there are two sections... Indexed collections and Unordered collections.  It really helped me to understand that if my @property is an NSMutableArray you need to look at the methods in the Indexed area and if your @property is a NSMutableSet you need to look at the Unordered documentation.

There are Required methods that you need to implement even if you don't plan to use them.