# iPhone Custom events for property value changes

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5

is it possible to add a custom event for a property value change?. I need to trigger a event when the value of a property changes.

Comment: you can use KVO(key value observing) or define your own method for setter and write custom events in it?Generally, KVO is  used for observing changes in the property value.

Comment: I know about custom setters. But how can implement KVO?.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813331/understanding-kvo-in-ios

Comment: http://nachbaur.com/blog/back-to-basics-using-kvo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to trigger an event in an object (called "observer") when a property changes in another object ("observed").

You can do this in two ways:

1. using the notification center, you can override the setter by posting a notification using any of NSNotificationCenter "postNotification:" methods,  then all interested observers will be notified provided they registered themselves for this kind of notification.
2. using KVO (Key-Value Observing) you must register the observer explicitly with the instance that has the property; e.g. if self wants to register to "instanceToObserve" property "myProperty":

```
[instanceToObserve addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myProperty" option:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

and then implement in the "self"'s class the "observation" function:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
// your implementation goes here
}
```

What to use of the two is up to you. Consider that KVO is automatically supported if you follow basic Cocoa convention rules, so no extra effort is required and no change is needed to the synthesized setter.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. for example

in the .h file

NSString *myString

in the .m file

```
- (NSString *)myString {
    //Custom event
    return myString;
}
```

This creates a property myString that can be used as self.myString

Comment: Sorry. I don't mean custom implementation of setter. I need to trigger another custom event when setter method is called. Without make any change to setter method.

Comment: Manali suggestion can work, you can re-implement the setter and inside the setter add the send a message ([NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName).

Answer (score 0):

You can use KVO(key value observing) or define your own method for setter and write custom events in it?Generally, KVO is used for observing changes in the property value.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813331/understanding-kvo-in-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813331/understanding-kvo-in-ios%5D)

http://nachbaur.com/blog/back-to-basics-using-kvo

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html