# Detecting when an object in a property did change Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers

I have a question that I suppose the answer is no, but I want to be sure. Is there any way to trigger a method when a class's property values were changed from another class?
An example, in iOS:

I've got `FirstViewController`, that get's an `NSString` from the server and saves it as `@property NSString helloString`. But it also saves it locally, using `NSSUserDefaults`, so when the user enters the app he will see the last `helloString` saved locally and when server answers (let's say after 5 seconds) it updates this `helloString` property.

Imagine that the user goes to `SecondViewController` (where we passed `helloString` with `prepareForSegue` in `FirstViewController` and saved as a property in `SecondViewController`). `SecondViewController` displays the saved `helloString`, and after 5 seconds server answers and updates the `helloString` property in `FirstViewController` (and of course to the `SecondViewController`).

Is there any way (I thought I could use `NSNotificationCenter`) to trigger a method in `SecondServerController` when `helloString` value changed in `FirstServerController`?

EDIT:

KVO is not a valid option because if we had a  `ThirdViewController` and user went from `FirstViewController` to `SecondViewController` and finally to `ThirdViewController`, and then go back to `FirstViewController` going through `SecondViewcontroller`, on `[FirstViewController removerObserver:forKeyPath:]` method that is inside `SecondViewController` would crash because `FirstViewController` was released from memory.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You'll probably find that this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282493/what-is-key-value-coding-and-key-value-observing-in-objective-c will help you. The answers give a good example of KVC (Key-Value Coding) and KVO (Key-Value Observing).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding KVO in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813331/understanding-kvo-in-ios)

Comment: Yet both questions lead to similar answer, I believe the question is different, this one asks about a pratical case while yours is just asking for a better theorical explanation about KVO.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the answer is yes, you can do that with [Key-Value observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

In the prepareForSegue you can add the observer:

```
[self addObserver:destinationViewController forKeyPath:@"helloString" options:<#(NSKeyValueObservingOptions)#> context:NULL];
```

Now, when helloString change, the method `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` will be called in SecondViewController.

Comment: That would be the solution if it had only 2 ViewControllers but it can cause crashes: If we have a `ThirdViewController` and user goes through First-> Second -> Third, the `FirstViewController` deallocates from memory and if the user goes back to `FirstViewController` it makes crash on `removeObserver`.  I will post a solution using `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`

Comment: Well obviously you remove the observer on the counterpart of the method it was added on. Added on `viewDidLoad`, remove on `dealloc`, viewDidAppear - viewDidDisappear, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, KVO will be overkill. You can simply override the property's setter method.

For example, in the SecondViewController.h, you have the property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *helloString;
```

In your SecondViewController.m file, add the method:

```
-(void)setHelloString:(NSString*)helloString {

    //This method gets called when the helloString property is assigned a value.
    //Save the value in the iVar
    _helloString = helloString;

    //Take whatever other action that is necessary.
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `nonatimic` has nothing to do with setter/getter generation. Getter/setter is generated due to `@property`, `nonatomic` just defines what type of setter/getter it generates.

Comment: As it says in the Apple Docs: `You can use the nonatomic property attribute to specify that synthesized accessors simply set or return a value directly, with no guarantees about what happens if that same value is accessed simultaneously from different threads`.

Comment: So if i have two setters for `helloString` in first and second viewcontrollers, and i modify `helloString` anywhere, both setters will be called?

Comment: The setter will be only for the class for which it has been overridden. You can create a cascade effect, by setting the secondViewController's property from the setter of the firstViewController

Comment: The custom setter should be in FirstViewController.m in this case (due to the question). `nonatomic` and `atomic` simply define the thread-safety of the setter and getter methods

Comment: I did thought about this solution, but I think @LordZsolt is cleaner. Thanks for your time!

Comment: ZeeMoon and @LordZsolt, Lord Zsolt is right. The nonatomic qualifier says that you won't be accessing the same property from different threads. The opposite of nonoatomic is atomic (which is the default). When a property is atomic the system adds lock commands to the getter and setter to avoid multiple threads accessing the property at the same time, but as Lord Zsolt says, it doesn't determine whether or not the getter/setter is generated.

Comment: It used to be that you had to add an @synthesize directive in order to get the system to create your getters and setters. Now it's automatic. `@dynamic` tells the system NOT to generate your getters/setters and trust you that they will be provided at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was not KVO or custom setter, for my case. I finally used `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` and post a notification from `FirstViewController` that will be observed in `SecondViewController`, and if any of those are released will not make the app crash.